# Will installing WebMatrix (and Consequently SQL Server CE) Break My Current Installation of SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-compact

We have a server that has (and needs to keep) SQL Server 2005.

We are hosting intranet sites on one server (server 1), but have a database on another server (server 2). One of these sites uses AJAX to go server-side (server 1) and then queries databases on server 2.

We are trying to cut out the middle man and we want to install WebMatrix (which comes with SQL Server CE) on the same server as the database (server 2), but this server already has SQL Server 2005 installed.

Will a simple WebMatrix install (i.e., SQL Server CE) break the SQL Server 2005 install?

My guess is that it won't, but the damage recovery would be considerable if it does.

I don't think it matters, but server 2 has Windows Server 2003.

Comment: I know SQL Server 2005 will live next to 2008 and 2012 just fine, just not sure about CE.  However the best suggestion I can offer is to grab another server and test it if possible.  That is the only way you can be sure nothing goes wrong.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, and the info. I will talk to my boss to see if we have at least a virtual server we can test or something.